# Encrypting OkHttp's HttpResponseCache

Tags: caching, encryption, okhttp

Are there any examples of using encryption to encrypt the disk-cache used by OkHttp's [HttpResponseCache](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/21a96eb/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpResponseCache.java#L51)? Naively, I don't think this is a very hard thing to do, but I'd appreciate any advice or experience to avoid security-pitfalls.

Without too many specifics, here's what I'm trying to achieve: a server that accept user's api-keys (typically 40-character random string) for established service X, and makes many API calls on the users behalf. The server won't persist user's api-keys, but a likely use case is that users will periodically call the server, supplying the api-key each time. Established service X uses reasonable rate-limiting, but supports conditional (ETag, If-Modified-Since) requests, so server-side caching by my server makes sense. The information is private though, and the server will be hosted on Heroku or the like, so I'd like to encrypt the files cached by HttpResponseCache so that if the machine is compromised, they don't yield any information.

My plan would be to create a wrapper around HttpResponseCache that accepts a secret key - which would actually be a hash of half of the api-key string. This would be used to AES-encrypt the cached contents and keys used by HttpResponseCache. Does that sound reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very difficult to do with the existing cache code. It's a journaled on-disk datastructure that is not designed to support privacy, and privacy is not a feature you can add on top.

One option is to mount an encrypted disk image and put the cache in there. Similar to Mac OS X's FileVault for example. If you can figure out how to do that, you're golden.

Your other option is to implement your own cache, using the existing cache as a guide. Fair warning: the OkResponseCache is subject to change in the next release!

Comment: Thanks for that and thanks for the warning - yep, having had a look, it looks like DiskLruCache would be the place I'd have to attack, and probably change a fair bit around re the bits that handle keys. Using an encrypted disk image is not a bad idea, but as the server would have potentially many users, there would ideally be distinctly encrypted areas for each user's data (encrypting using a secret-key based on a hash of the user's api-key).

Comment: Is there any plan to support this in okhttp?

Comment: As above, your best option is an encrypted disk image.